# Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp returned 302 error and undefined response

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I've tried to scrape and parse JSON data. While the below URL returns JSON data on browser, below code will generate an error by Google saying "Exception: Request failed for https://rate.tmall.com/list_detail_rate.htm returned code 302". 
Also, response is valued at undefined and I could not track anything from the response.

How can I solve the issue? Thanks a lot.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://rate.tmall.com/list_detail_rate.htm");
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I got it. I need to bring the cookies in the header. :)

Comment: Could you elaborate your answer because I am facing same issue? I have very long URL so I have used FDL to short url then pass short url to UrlFetchAPP and facing 302 response code, so Could you help me to solve this issue?